# (Preferably) Encrypted Server Backups

Tags: linux, backup, encryption

I have somehow managed to purchase a VPS after collecting money for sometime, now problem is i cant find a way to backup the server. My previous approach was:

Got a webdav account from mydisk.se, mounted it on the vps, used duplicity and created encrypted backups.

Problem is it was only 2G, and its running out of space, at my own place i dont have a stable internet connection else i have a 500G drive that i could surely use for backups. The vps has a 12G HD, and i would like to backup /home, /root, /etc, /var/ (specially log and www).

Any ideas are welcomed.

[EDIT]
I am more of looking for resource of setting up a backup-point or such(i know how to setup a backup server, but i cant as i dont have stable connection or the money to buy another VPS/disk for backup) , i have already got the tools needed.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I'm following what you need. Using duplicity you can exactly what you ask. If you only want /home, /root, /etc, /var/log and /var/www then only back those up. You would do this by setting the source to / and adding exclusions for /proc, /tmp, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use zyxBackup+GPG it is a better alternative than duplicity:
http://www.sysadmin.md/secure-backup-on-remote-server-using-zyxbackup-and-gpg.html

The solution offers you to customize that folders to backup and could be used for servers and desktops. You'll need only FTP or SSH access to the backup server

Comment: Why is this solution superior to duplicity?

Answer (score 0):

Use a cloud storage provider to store your backups. Unlimited space and you only pay what you use. So, no need to invest in the capacity needed for future growth or long-term contracts.

I've used Amazon S3 to do this, but you could also look at Rackspace Cloudfiles.

Answer (score 0):

I've used duplicity with Amazon S3 for backup needs of my VPS in the past. The costs are not that bad. I've also used duplicity with [Exavault](http://www.exavault.com) before as well before starting to use S3.